# Pandas: Storing Dataframe in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nested

I am rather new to Pandas and am currently running into a problem when trying to insert a Dataframe inside a Dataframe.

What I want to do:
I have multiple simulations and corresponding signal files and I want all of them in one big DataFrame. So I want a DataFrame which has all my simulation parameters and also my signals as an nested DataFrame. It should look something like this:

```
SimName | Date | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 |  Signal 1 |  Signal 2 |
Name 1  | 123  | XYZ         | XYZ         | DataFrame | DataFrame |
Name 2  | 456  | XYZ         | XYZ         | DataFrame | DataFrame |
```

Where SimName is my Index for the big DataFrame and every entry in Signal 1 and Signal 2 is an individuall DataFrame.

My idea was to implement this like this:

```
big_DataFrame['Signal 1'].loc['Name 1']
```

But this results in an ValueError:

> Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

Is it possible to have this nested DataFrames in Pandas?

Nico

Comment: You should show your initial data...

Comment: What do you mean with intitial data? For now I create the DataFrame with a list of all simulations as indixies and then add each simulation data after another

Comment: Why would you want to store a df in a df? Look into [pandas panel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html).

Comment: @Parfait [Panel is being deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dsintro-deprecate-panel)

Answer (score 1):

The 'pointers' referred to at the end of [ns63sr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648693) could be implemented as a class, e.g...

Definition:

```
class df_holder:
    def __init__(self, df): 
        self.df = df
```

Set:

```
df.loc[0,'df_holder'] = df_holder(df)
```

Get:

```
df.loc[0].df_holder.df
```

Answer (score 0):

the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) say that only `Series` can be within a `DataFrame`. However, passing `DataFrames` seems to work as well. Here is an exaple assuming that none of the columns is in `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

signal_df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3],
                          'Y': [10,20,30]}  )

big_df = pd.DataFrame({'SimName': ['Name 1','Name 2'],
                       'Date ':[123  , 456 ],
                       'Parameter 1':['XYZ', 'XYZ'],
                       'Parameter 2':['XYZ', 'XYZ'],
                       'Signal 1':[signal_df, signal_df],
                       'Signal 2':[signal_df, signal_df]}  )

big_df.loc[0,'Signal 1']
big_df.loc[0,'Signal 1'][X]
```

This results in:

```
out1:    X  Y
      0  1  10
      1  2  20
      2  3  30

out2: 0    1
      1    2
      2    3
      Name: X, dtype: int64
```

In case nested dataframes are not properly working, you may implement some sort of pointers that you store in `big_df` that allow you to access the signal dataframes stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `big_DataFrame['Signal 1'].loc['Name 1']`  you should use

```
big_DataFrame.loc['Name 1','Signal 1']
```

Comment: While this might be syntactically more concise it doesn't avoid the issue.