# Accessing a data frame that is generated inside for loop out side of the loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, anaconda

I have a data frame that I generated inside for loop. I am trying to save this data frame so that I can access it outside of the loop. I have a snippet of my code below.

```
my_excel_sample = pd.read_excel(r"mypath\mydata.xlsx",sheet_name=None)

for tabs in my_excel_sample.keys():
    actualData = pd.DataFrame(removeEmptyColumns(my_excel_sample[tabs],0))
    data = replaceNanValues(actualData,0)
    data = renameColumns(data,0)
    data = removeFooters(data,0)
    data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    data = pd.DataFrame(RowMerger(data,0))
```

Now I want to use `data` outside of the loop. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: why not declare the variable outside of your loop so you would still have it when the loop is over.
 Intitalize it with anything   ```actualData = ""  ``` before the loop starts

Comment: @kareem_emad Look at the `loop` and `df` creation. H is using the loop to create dataframes iteratively. This cannot be done before for loop starts. He needs that loop to get `tabs` which is used in `df` creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating several dataframes iteratively inside `for` loop and storing it in variable `data`.

You can just add the dataframes `(data)` to a list and then access them anytime you want.

Try this :

```
my_excel_sample = pd.read_excel(r"mypath\mydata.xlsx",sheet_name=None)
final_df_list = []

for tabs in my_excel_sample.keys():
    actualData = pd.DataFrame(removeEmptyColumns(my_excel_sample[tabs],0))
    data = replaceNanValues(actualData,0)
    data = renameColumns(data,0)
    data = removeFooters(data,0)
    data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    data = pd.DataFrame(RowMerger(data,0))

    final_df_list.append(data)

print(final_df_list)
```

If you ave any type of identifier that you can use to recognize the dataframes later, I would suggest you to use a dictionary. Make the identifier as `keys` and variable `data` as `value`.

Here is an example where I take serial number as key :

```
my_excel_sample = pd.read_excel(r"mypath\mydata.xlsx",sheet_name=None)

final_df_dict = dict()
ind = 0

for tabs in my_excel_sample.keys():
    actualData = pd.DataFrame(removeEmptyColumns(my_excel_sample[tabs],0))
    data = replaceNanValues(actualData,0)
    data = renameColumns(data,0)
    data = removeFooters(data,0)
    data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    data = pd.DataFrame(RowMerger(data,0))

    final_df_dict[ind] = data
    ind += 1

print(final_df_dict)
```

Comment: This is great. Now I know how to address this problem for future implementation. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: a quick question, however, I am wondering if there is any way to make or define the final_df_dict as a data frame because eventually, I want to save the final data as csv?

Comment: Yes you can store a `datafame` inside another `dataframe` but that would become a little confusing. You can check <<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648167/pandas-storing-dataframe-in-dataframe>>